# Is it necessary to call process.exit() after handling a SIGTERM event in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js it's possible to respond to `SIGTERM` signal events.

From the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#signal-events):

```
function handle(signal) {
  console.log(`Received ${signal}`);
}

process.on('SIGTERM', handle);
```

Is it necessary or advisable to terminate the process with `process.exit()` in the event handler?

For example:

```
async function closeGracefully() {
  await closeDbConnection();
  await stopApplication();
  process.exit();
}

process.on('SIGTERM', closeGracefully);
```

Comment: If you just catch the signal and not exit, someone or something is going to kill the process more forceful sooner or later. You better be nice and exit as you were asked to, after you cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You should allow the event loop to complete all tasks and node exit itself. Calling `process.exit()` might terminate ongoing work unexpectedly.

https://kostasbariotis.com/why-you-should-not-use-process-exit/